# Add the same string from textbox in two lines listbox?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add the same string typed in the texbox in the two lines of the listbox, as shown in the image below?

[image]

```
private void metroButton10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add("Next station: " + metroTextBox1.Text);
        listBox2.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine)
        metroTextBox1.Clear();
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes?  What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: Do you have any code you tried with?

Comment: The most awesome part about programming is: You can make everything happen, whatever you want! Which means this is possible, yes :-)

Comment: I know how to do this to add one string, but with two I have a problem because eg environemnt.NewLine does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Next Station: "+textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Station: " + textBox1.Text);
    }
```

You Can't use new line. Because listbox can contain one item in a line.

Comment: Was it really that easy? I was tired of Environment.NewLine for a long time. Thanks thats works !!

Comment: Yeah it's easy by this way. If you think it works, then you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: But why you need to add those in a listbox?

Comment: I am workingon my project  to display the contents of the listbox on the LED display.

Comment: Ok fine. you can use RichTextBox. Its supports multi-colour also.

Comment: Check the Picture , I made it and use RichTextBox for displaying result .    https://techsflow.com/Sumon/ip.PNG

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can add same string typed in the textbox in the two lines of the listbox as;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("NextStation: " + textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Station: " +textBox1.Text);
    }
```

[image: ss after the button hit]